# Previous correct radio buttons disappearing when I miss a radio button in the middle

Tags: javascript, radio-button, dom-events

I'm facing one issue here,

I am trying to validate at least one radio button to be answered to each question,
but the error here is when I miss some question to answer, I am getting alert, it is fine, but my previous correct answers also disappearing, I mean the page is loading from the start it seems.

[Workingfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ExAh/1/).

You can see my sample question form here:

```
<form name="myform" >
<div id="Q1" class="question">
<h3>1. How convenient is our company to use?</h3>
</div>
<div id="A1"class="answers">

<input type="radio" name="Q1ans" value="1">Extremely convenient<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q1ans" value="2">Very convenient<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q1ans" value="3">Moderately convenient<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q1ans" value="4">Not at all convenient<br>

</div>
<div id="Q2" class="question">
<h3>2. How professional is our company?</h3>
</div>
<div id="A2"class="answers">

<input type="radio" name="Q2ans" value="1">Extremely professional<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q2ans" value="2">Very professional<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q2ans" value="3">Moderately professional<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q2ans" value="4">Not at all professional<br>

</div>
<div id="Q3" class="question">
<h3>3. Compared to our competitors, is our product quality better, worse, or about the same?</h3>
</div>
<div id="A3"class="answers">

<input type="radio" name="Q3ans" value="1">Much better<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q3ans" value="2">some what better<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q3ans" value="3">slightly better<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q3ans" value="4">worse<br>

</div>
<div id="Q4" class="question">
<h3>4. How responsive is our company?</h3>
</div>
<div id="A4"class="answers">

<input type="radio" name="Q4ans" value="1">Much better<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q4ans" value="2">some what better<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q4ans" value="3">slightly better<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q4ans" value="4">worse<br>

</div>
<div id="Q5" class="question">
<h3>5. Do you like our company, neither like nor dislike it, or dislike it?</h3>
</div>
<div id="A5"class="answers">

<input type="radio" name="Q5ans" value="1">Like a great deal<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q5ans" value="2">Like a little<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q5ans" value="3">Dislike a little<br>
<input type="radio" name="Q5ans" value="4">Dislike a great deal<br>

</div><br><br>
<button type="submit" onclick="validate()">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That fiddle was pretty rough, here it is a little better, http://jsfiddle.net/8ExAh/3/ (it includes the answer given below).  Maybe it will help with some other issues that script was having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply change:

```
onclick="validate()"
```

to:

```
onclick="return validate()"
```

and it will have the desired behavior. I think this is what you were trying to do, but the onclick() call never returned the value from validate().